# Validate input and prevent code injection

Tags: validation, security, code-injection, code-inspection

I have a general software security question.
I have an application. This application can receive a file as an input and write it to the disk. 
This file is a text file and i want to make sure the user is not trying to write a script that will be saved on the disk.

FYI - operating system is Linux.

What i have so far is: 
1) I can write it with limited permissions. (i do not think this is secure enough)
2) I want to verify this is not a script.  << How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set a unprivileged user and write that file disabling execution and reading for other user i think it's the best option.
The second option is impracticable , but you can try to make things difficult to an attacker:

1. Remove some special delimiters, e.g. PHP's

   Remove (if you can)some special characters used normally, e.g. {},<>, etc

   Remove any non printablechar (for partially-avoiding any binaryfile)